# Chris Banes's PullToRefresh Library Scrolling Direction

Tags: android, android-scrollview, pull-to-refresh

I currently using the Chris Banes's PullToRefresh library and I am using the library associated with scrollview. The link below is the library I am using.

https://github.com/chrisbanes/Android-PullToRefresh/blob/master/library/src/com/handmark/pulltorefresh/library/PullToRefreshListView.java

How can I get the scrolling direction of the scrollview? I have tried in another project which can get the scrollview's scrolling position through method onScrollChanged.

Please help me to overcome to barrel. Thank very much.

Comment: have you got the solution. Please post as answer if you have one. I need this Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is Late may be but, I have get the solutions.

**getScrollY()** helped me to get the scroll Direction

```
mPullRefreshScrollView
            .setOnRefreshListener(new OnRefreshListener<ScrollView>() {

                @Override
                public void onRefresh(
                        PullToRefreshBase<ScrollView> refreshView) {


                    Log.e("SCROLL DIRCECTION",
                            mPullRefreshScrollView.getScrollY() + "");

                    if (mPullRefreshScrollView.getScrollY() < 0) {

                          // SCROLL_DIRECTION_UP

                    } else if (mPullRefreshScrollView.getScrollY() > 0) {

                         // SCROLL_DIRECTION_DOWN


                    }

                }

            });
```

Hope this helps :) cheers